# Problem with Alignment of Tabular Data Using siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

I am trying to align numerical data in different rows along the decimal point. I have been trying to use column type `S` of `siunitx`. I have searched and tried different things but no success yet. Here is my MWE that I have tried:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    % Commands to add space before and after a horizonal line
    \newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       % = 'top' strut
    \newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} % = 'bottom' strut

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!t]
    \caption{My Table Example.}
    \label{example}
    \centering

    % I use column type S for columns 2 and 3. Columns 1 and 4 use c.
    \begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]c}
    \Xhline{0.8pt}  

    This is & {This is} & {This is} & Here is \\
    Column 1 & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & Column 4\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}

    {$A_1$} & {1.02} & {$10.54$} & {$0.45$} \Tstrut\Bstrut\\
    \hline
    {$A_2$} & {43.23} & {$-3.62$} & {$-0.32$} \Tstrut\Bstrut\\
    \hline
    {$A_3$} & {1.30}  & {$7.68$} & {$-5.85$} \Tstrut\Bstrut\\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

This compiles successfully. However, the data in column 2 and column 3 for which type `S` is used, is still not aligned around the decimal point. Here is the output:

[image: Output after compilation]

I will be much thankful any hints and advice.

Regards

A.

Comment: Erh `{$ ... $}` hides the data from `siunitx`, leave that for headlines. Just write `...`

Comment: @daleif That's why I used S column type for both Column 2 and Column 3. I use $ in Column 3 but not in Column 2. Columns 1 and 4 use c instead of S. Still, result is the same for all the columns.

Comment: I misspoke, it is `{ ... }` this is hiding it from `S`, but `{$...$}` is also wrong as an `S` column is already math mode. You don't see data entries in the `siunitx` manual marked with `{1.02}`

Comment: @daleif So right. This solves the problem. Thanks a bundle. So simple and this makes me think probably what a stupid question I've asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get rid of the unnecessary and, in fact, destructive mode of encasing the numbers in an `S` column in curly braces. While you're at it, do get rid of the `$` symbols in the `S`-type columns as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

% Commands to add space before and after an \hline
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       %'top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} %'bottom' strut
\newcommand\TBstrut{\Tstrut\Bstrut} % top and bottom strut

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{My Table Example.}
\label{example}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} c S[table-format= 2.2]
                      S[table-format= 2.2]
                      S[table-format=-1.2] @{}}
\toprule 
This is  & {This is}  & {This is}  & {This is} \\
Column 1 & {Column 2} & {Column 3} & {Column 4}\\
\midrule
$A_1$ &  1.02 & 10.54 &  0.45 \Bstrut  \\
\hline
$A_2$ & 43.23 & -3.62 & -0.32 \TBstrut \\
\hline
$A_3$ &  1.30 &  7.68 & -5.85 \Tstrut  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `\thead` for the column heads, instead of two rows. Your `S` columns were not aligned on the decimal dot, because your numbers were surrounded by pairs of braces, which means they were ordinary data, which had to be centred. I added the `caption` package to have a more sensible spacing between caption and table.

Your strut commands are needless if you use the rules from `booktabs`, which include some padding above and below. Anyway, there are already such strut commands in the `bigstrut` package which comes  with `multirow`, and a single command adds both some height and some depth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell, caption, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{My Table Example.}
\label{example}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=-1.2]c}
\toprule
\thead{This is \\ Column 1}& {\thead{This is \\Column 2}} & {\thead{This is \\ Column 3}} & \thead{Here is \\Column 4} \\
\midrule[0.8pt]
{$A_1$} & 1.02 & 10.54 & {$0.45$} \\
\midrule
{$A_2$} & 43.23 & -3.62 & {$-0.32$} \\
\midrule
{$A_3$} & 1.30 & 7.68 & {$-5.85$} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]